Owl Carousel 2.2.1 Turn off Hover Image
I'll be honest....I'm not the greatest at HTML, CSS, and JS...but I get by. I installed a pre-loaded wordpress template and it uses Owl Carousel 2.2.1 to scroll through blog posts on the front page.
The current behavior, out of the box, shows the blog title, read more link, comment link, etc. and then a transparent background. When you hover over the display block, the image that is part of the blog post, is shown, but is zoomed in and only part of the image (which is fine with me).
The behavior I'm trying to fix is the hover. I'm trying to turn that behavior off so that the background image is just always there. I just can't figure out where to make that change. I've combed through all the js, css, and html to try and find it but can't seem to locate it.
Here is a copy of the css for the owl carousel, which is where I'm pretty sure the setting is or should be.
.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
   /* -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* fix firefox animation glitch */ }
  .owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* fix for flashing background */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); }
  .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,
  .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled,
  .owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled{
    display: none; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
  .owl-carousel .owl-dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-loading {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 0; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
    visibility: hidden; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-grab {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grab; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
    direction: rtl; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
    float: right; }

/* No Js */
.no-js .owl-carousel {
  display: block; }

/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Animate Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .animated {
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both; }

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
  z-index: 0; }

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
  z-index: 1; }

.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut; }

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }
  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Auto Height Plugin
 */
.owl-height {
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out; }

/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Lazy Load Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease; }

.owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy {
  transform-style: preserve-3d; }  


/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Video Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000; }

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: url("owl.video.play.png") no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 100ms ease; }

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
      transform: scale(1.3, 1.3); }

.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn,
.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon {
  display: none; }

.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease; }

.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

This is what the behavior looks like:
Example of hover

Welcome. Please provide a [mre], preferably as a runnable snippet

It's tough to just look at this CSS and know.  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; looks like a candidate.
I'd recommend opening your debugger in your browser (F12) and looking at the carousel elements, and toggling CSS properties on or off until you find the one you are looking for.
A simple tutorial here if you are unfamiliar. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css
